# How can I determine which properties exist/are filled in my database - and create rank - c#

Tags: c#

I'm receiving products from a server and the response looks like this:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "city": "New York",
            "title": "Pepsi",
            "brand": "Coca-Cola"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "city": "Seatle",
            "title": "Fanta",
            "brand": "Idk"
        },
        {   
            "id":"3",
            "city": "D.C W.",
            "title": "Snickers",
            "brand": "Fat"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've previously also inserted some products in my Db... and I need to compare which properties already exist in my database.

The more properties are the persisted the higher the rank is.

This "Rank" basically determines how well the data is synchronized.

For example if two properties from a request exist in my database, that is rank 2,
if all of them exist in my database that is rank 3 for instance.

Here's what I tried:

```
    private IQueryable<ProductDto> OrderingProducts(IQueryable<Product> databaseProducts, RequestDto request)
    {
        foreach(var item in request.Products)
        { // Probably makes no sense.. :(
          ord.AddRange(products.Where(c.Title == user.title && c.Brand == item.brand));
          ord.AddRange(products.Where(c => c.City == item.city));
          ord.AddRange(products.Where(c => c.Title == item.title ));
          ord.AddRange(products.Where(c => c.Brand == item.brand));
        }

    }
```

Idea was to receive both lists, and to somehow compare which properties data exist in my database.

I'm stuck on this, any kind of help would be awesome!

Comment: I assume `products` is supposed to be `databaseProducts` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will get the ranking for you, but I don't know what type `request.Products` is, or what you want to do with it afterwards.

```cs
foreach (var item in request.Products)
{
    var match = databaseProducts.SingleOrDefault(dp => dp.Id = item.Id);
    int rank = match == null ? -1 : GetRank(item, match);
    // TODO do something with rank
}

int GetRank(RequestTypeUnknown item, Product match)
{   
    return (item.city == match.City ? 1 : 0) +
           (item.title == match.Title ? 1 : 0) +
           (item.brand == match.Brand ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: I like this.  To make things a little more clear I think I'd use a ternary operator in the `GetRank` function instead of the convert to int32.  `return (item.City == match.City ? 1 : 0) + ...`.  Just to help with readability.

Answer (score 0):

The response is in json format so you could deserialize it

```
public class Response
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Usage

```
Response res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);

foreach(var product in res.Products)
{
    //product.Id
}
```

Comment: One would assume that `RequestDto` is the deserialized form of the JSON.

Comment: @SamAxe well the question initially seemed clueless as to how to access the property values

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks.